# Unsupported Feature exception fetchDmlReturnParams

Tags: java, ojdbc

I have this code

```
String sql = "insert into colortable (string, color, cid) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql,keyProperties.toArray(new String[0]));
ps.executeBatch();
final ResultSet rst = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
 while (rst.next()) {
    final BigDecimal bigDecimal = rst.getBigDecimal(1);
    if (bigDecimal != null) {
      ids.add(bigDecimal.intValueExact());
    }
  }
```

When the code arrive to *rst.next* i obtain the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchDmlReturnParams(OracleStatement.java:4959) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleReturnResultSet.next(OracleReturnResultSet.java:63) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
```

I found that the problem is in this part of the ojdbc driver.

```
if (!this.statement.returnParamsFetched) {
      this.statement.fetchDmlReturnParams();
      this.statement.setupReturnParamAccessors();
}
```

In particular the function *this.statement.fetchDmlReturnParams();* is not implemented.

Now my question is ho to avoid to call this function in particular returnParamFetched can be set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that my application  really execute is

```
 try {
  final String sql = "insert into colortable (string, color, cid) values (?,?,?)";
  final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {"ID"});
  ps.setString(1, "TEST1");
  ps.setString(2, "FFFFFF");
  ps.setInt(3, 1);
  ps.addBatch();
  ps.setString(1, "TEST2");
  ps.setString(2, "AAAAAA");
  ps.setInt(3, 1);
  ps.addBatch();
  ps.executeBatch();
  final ResultSet rst = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
  rst.getMetaData();
  if (rst != null){
    while (rst.next()) {
      final BigDecimal bigDecimal = rst.getBigDecimal(1);
      System.out.println(bigDecimal);
      Assert.notNull(bigDecimal);
    }
  }
  ps.close();
}catch (final SQLException e){
  System.out.println(e);
}finally {
}
```

I create a test case to test this pice of code, I try with different ojdbc and i find that the latest ojdb8 solve the problem.